# How to map HttpResponse in a Object Java

Tags: java, json, rest, get, httpclient

I'm making a GET REST call via HttpClient:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(endpoint))
    .GET()
    .header("Authorization", authHeader)
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(
    request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

How can I map the response in the MyObject object? Is it correct to intercept it as a String first? also, I would need to pass a string as a path parameter, but I don't know where to add it.

Thanks for the support!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another commonly used library for this is Jackson ObjectMapper. Using ObjectMapper, you can map the body to an object like this:

```
String json = response.body(); // "{ \"name\" : \"Nemo\", \"type\" : \"Fish\" }";
Animal nemo = objectMapper.readValue(json, Animal.class);
```

For a step by step guide, see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial#2-json-to-java-object

Comment: How should I pass a string as a path parameter?

Comment: Path parameters are passed in via the `.uri(URI.create(endpoint))` portion of your code. For example, with a path param called `exampleId`, your code would look like this `.uri(URI.create("http://example.com/examples/ + exampleId))`.

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches to your problem.

1. Simplest: Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), which can map a JSON response automatically to a given Object type (Instead of `theJsonString` you can also pass a `InputStream` or similar):

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
gson.fromJson(theJsonString, MyObject.class);
```

2. Medium: What you are doing is already correct. You only need to parse the `String` you are getting to your `MyObject`.
3. Hard: You can write your own `HttpResponse.BodyHandler<MyObject>`, which converts the response to a `MyObject`.

If you are able to use external libraries, definetly use Gson or similar.